# One FB application to more than one FB Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to add a an FB application to more than one FB Page.After the user's authentication , rediraction to my application's url I can't find a way for the application to know the page which the request was made. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will get the page id in the signed request.

FYI: [Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do. If you decode the `signed_request` data POSTed to your page, you can see what page is 'looking' at your app (i.e. which page the app has been installed on).

If you decode the data (e.g. in PHP you can do: `print_r( $facebook->getSignedRequest() );` to print the decoded version), you will see something like:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1234567890
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )
    [user] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
)
```

The `$response['page']['id']` is the ID of the Page that is looking at your app at that moment. You can store the IDs of the page that have installed your app, and check it with this to determine which content to load up.

Comment: But this info is available only when the application is inside the Page tab, not on the authentication redirection to the application url

Comment: Before you authorise the user, change the `redirect_url` to include something like `page_id=12345` in the URL. After the user is authenticated, read the `page_id` in the URL and redirect the user to the correct page where they came from.